# Splash screen not relaunching when relaunching after Application memory collected

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-lifecycle, application-lifecycle

So in general the common approach to Splash Screen Activities is something like this:

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity
    @override
    protected void onResume() {
    //Create a thread
     new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Do heavy work in background
                ((MyApplication)getApplication()).loadFromDb();
                startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,     MainActivity.class));
                finish(); //End this activity
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

The problem I found for this case is that when the app is in the background and it gets memmory collected, when you return it to the foreground Application.onCreate is called again, the Splash activity doesn't get called and instead whatever activity was open when the App went into background is opened. How do you make sure that in this situation the SplashScreen is the one that's launched?

Edit1: Btw, I've tried setting android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" for the Splash Screen Activity, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: In the manifest register your own instance of the application:  <application android:name="fullinstanceclass" ...>  in the oncreate of your application instance launch your splash ?

Comment: @d3n13d1 but how will that play out with the MAIN/LAUNCHER activity... currently I mark the SplashScreen Activity as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've figured out a solution that works:

Extend the `Application` class, add a boolean field `isSplashInitialized` and set it to `false` in Application's `onStart`. Then inside your Splash Activity when you're done your initialization stuff within it, before calling `finish()`, set Application's `isSplashInitialized` field to `true`.
Then have a `BaseActivity` class that all your Activities extend. In it extend `onCreate()` and after calling `super.onCreate();` do the following:

```
if (!(this instanceof SplashActivity) && !MyApplication.getIntance().isSplashInitialized()) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```